# An example of a strange behavior of a function replace()

Tags: javascript, function

Why, in the example below, the string `'a'` is not replaced with the function definition?

In my opinion, in the following code

```
let f = function() {};
console.log('a'.replace('a', f)); //the result is: undefined
```

the string `'a'` should be replaced with this `'function() {}'`
but is replaced with `'undefined'`.

When we do the same with an object:

```
let o = {};
console.log('a'.replace('a', o)); //the result is: [object Object]
```

the conversion to a string is performed and `'a'` is replaced with `'[object Object]'`.

When we force the conversion to string:

```
let f = function() {};
console.log('a'.replace('a', '' + f)); //the result is: function f() {}
```

the conversion to string is performed too and `'a'` is replaced with `function f() {}'`.

And here is the executable code:

```js
let f = function() {};
console.log('a'.replace('a', f)); //the result is: undefined

let o = {}
console.log('a'.replace('a', o)); //the result is: [object Object]

console.log('a'.replace('a', '' + f)); //the result is: function f() {}
```

Comment: There is no conversion, there is only string replacement and your function doesn’t have a string to replace.

Answer (score 3):

If the second argument to `replace()` is a function, the function is called with the matching string, and the return value of the function is used as the replacement. This is more useful when you're replacing a regular expression match, since the matching string can vary and you can make the replacement depend on what was matched, but it still happens when replacing a literal string.

```js
console.log('a'.replace('a', function(x) {
  console.log("function was called, arg = ", x);
  return 'b';
}));
```

You can use `f.toString()` to convert the function to its source code.

Answer (score 0):

> Resource from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)
>
> You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement string. (Note: the above-mentioned special replacement patterns do not apply in this case.) Note that the function will be invoked multiple times for each full match to be replaced if the regular expression in the first parameter is global.

Basically, that function `f` doesn't return anything (`undefined`).

**Look at this with the function which returns a specific value:**

```js
let f = function() {
  return 'Ele from Stack';
};
console.log('a'.replace('a', f)); //the result is: Ele from Stack
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the MDN doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for the `String.prototype.replace` , it states the following :

> You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the
>   function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The
>   function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement
>   string. (Note: the above-mentioned special replacement patterns do not
>   apply in this case.) Note that the function will be invoked multiple
>   times for each full match to be replaced if the regular expression in
>   the first parameter is global.

So for your snippet :

```
let f = function() {};
console.log('a'.replace('a', f)); //the result is: undefined
```

The return value for function f is undefined for all obvious reasons. And thereby the replacement.

As an extension, try this :

```
let f = function() {};
console.log('ab'.replace('a', f));
```

You would get the output as `undefinedb`

And if you may do this :

```
let f = function() {return 'Hola'};
console.log('ab'.replace('a', f));
```

Guess what you may get the output as ? It would be `Holab`.